# connect apps with WiFi Direct or hotSpot in Air/AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, air, starling-framework, ane

is it possible to connect my game/apps installed on separate android &iOS devices with **AS3 / Air** to communicate either through wireless (without access point), maybe **WiFi direct or hotpot** or any other means?

in fact i want devices connect each other anywhere, anytime - even when they don't have access to internet, like transfer file apps (Zapya,share it,...)

FYI recently i search a lot but unfortunately i don't find ANE(Air Native Extension) or library for do this

Comment: Did you look into this? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/ServerSocket.html

Comment: as I know the AIR Socket communication works only in Desktop application

Comment: Also i want the Devices connect each other without any internet access point like transfer file apps (share it, zapya, ...)

Comment: Quote from the prtovided link (it is a good practice to actually read the answers you get): *AIR profile support: This feature is supported on all desktop operating systems, on iOS (starting with AIR 3.8), and on Android (starting with AIR 3.8).*

Comment: I read that your link carefully even create the example of that link but as [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181993/air-for-android-socketserver-over-wifi) i didnt get my answer because socket communication (if even answer in android or ios  devices ) needs server to response the clients so the devices need internet to communicate each other

Comment: Yes, the main problem here is to figure the address of the server socket without additional services on the Internet.

Comment: Thank you @Organis , for more clarify I edit my question

Comment: @Organis do you know [link](https://allseenalliance.org) , is it help to find a solution?

Comment: Totally unfamiliar, sorry. Probably you should look into ANE creation tools.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look of [WifiDirectANE](https://github.com/Sanwuthree/WifiDirectANE) in github, but it is for Android only.

> there are two tools,  wifi and wifi-direct
>   WifiANE can open WIfi,close Wifi ,openWiFiAp ,Close Wifi ap, get Wifi State  etc...
>   WifiDirectANE can let you device connect with other device by wifi-direct . 
>   in ane. i provide some function like :
>   Look up near device , connect device ,createWifiGroup  etc...